# Moving household stuff from Bangalore(India) to Nepal(Chitwan district)

Tags: relocation, india

What would be the best way to move household stuff from Bangalore to Nepal? Household stuff includes six medium steel boxes, television, refrigerator and 3 sets of roof fans. My father was working in the Indian army (Gurkha regiment) and now he would like to settle in Nepal.

I want to know especially about customs rules as well as shipping options for moving these electronic items from India to Nepal.

I am planning to load everything on the same train in which we will be travelling and after reaching Gorakhpur (Uttar Pradesh) we are not sure what to do further.

Are there other ways like hiring packers and movers which can directly deliver the stuff to Nepal?